# Что лучше использовать: Gulp или плагины в vs code?

Tags: html, веб-программирование, frontend, gulp

Недавно начал изучать frontend, и в курсе есть глава про gulp. Для меня это все выглядит на данный момент сложновато и многословно, и я не знаю, стоит ли после его основ углубляться в его изучение когда есть разные плагины в vs code, которые выполняют те же самые функции. Например: плагин watch sass, который компилирует sass в css; плагин live server - тот же самый browsersync, но для активации можно просто нажать одну кнопку в vs.

Comment: Gulp - сборщик (таск-менеджер), а VSC в первую очередь - текстовый редактор, если кто-то написал плагин для "компилирования" SASS в CSS, то это не значит, что VSC может заменить Gulp, применение этих программ разное, абсолютно. Возьмите какой-нибудь [roadmap](https://roadmap.sh/frontend) и изучайте постепенно.

Comment: Представьте что Вы передаете проект другому разработчику который будет в дальнейшем с ним работать. Когда Вы его передаете с Gulp он сразу в принципе понимает что с ним делать и вопросов никаких не возникнет, он просто посмотрит в gulpfile и будет знать какие таски там есть и тп. Или же Вы передаете проект без этого и ему нужно думать и гадать, а как Вы это все счастье компилили. Коммерческая разработка таким образом не ведется.

Answer (score 1):

Конечно, Gulp), я знаю, что тебе будет тяжело с самого начала, но без него тебе было бы некуда идти.
Зачем использовать Gulp вместо плагинов VSCode?

1. Экономия времени в несколько секунд, вместо использования плагинов vscode вы можете создать сборку gulp (на ютубе много роликов по этому поводу), и она запустит все ваши плагины одновременно, например (минимизация файлов html, css, js), что занимает несколько секунд.
2. Автоматизировать большое количество задач, все это можно сделать с помощью нескольких npm-команд